# Date-Time Formatting in XSLT 2.0

Tags: datetime, xslt, xslt-2.0, datetime-format, xslt-grouping

I have an XML which has a field with Date-Time stamp as below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?

<root>
    <row>
        <Code>A1</Code>
        <ID>20202020</ID>
        <Date-Changed>April 01, 2021, 1:13 pm</Date-Changed>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Code>A1</Code>
        <ID>20202020</ID>
        <Date-Changed>April 01, 2021, 1:14 pm</Date-Changed>
    </row>
</root>
```

I need to convert this to a format which the XSLT understands so that I can filter only the rows which have the latest Date-time stamp. I have figured out a way to filter on the records with the latest Date-time stamp. However, the Date-time stamp format in the XML is throwing the logic off where I am filtering on the latest changed record.

What can I do so that my XSLT can understand the Date-time format in the above XML and output the below XML?

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <row>
          <Code>A1</Code>
          <ID>1234ABCD</ID>
          <Date-Changed>2021-04-01T13:14:00</Date-Changed>
       </row>
    </root>
```

My XSLT looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <root>
                <xsl:for-each select="root">
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="(concat(ID, Code))">
                        <xsl:variable name="Mod_Dt">
                            <xsl:value-of select="max(current-group()/Date-Changed/xs:dateTime(.))"/>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <row>
                            <Code>
                                <xsl:value-of select="(current-group()[Date-Changed=$Mod_Dt]/Code)"/>
                            </Code>
                            <ID>
                                <xsl:value-of select="(current-group()[Date-Changed=$Mod_Dt]/ID)"/>
                            </ID>
                            <Date-Changed>
                                <xsl:value-of select="(current-group()[Date-Changed=$Mod_Dt]/Date-Changed)"/>
                            </Date-Changed>
                        </row>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </root>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function to convert the given string to a valid dateTime - for example:

```
<xsl:function name="my:string-to-dateTime">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <!-- extract components -->
    <xsl:variable name="parts" select="tokenize($string, ',\s|\s|:')"/>
    <!-- adjust -->
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="index-of(('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'), substring($parts[1], 1, 3))" />
    <xsl:variable name="H12" select="number($parts[4]) mod 12" />
    <xsl:variable name="H" select="if($parts[6]='pm') then $H12 + 12 else $H12" />
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:sequence select="xs:dateTime(concat($parts[3], format-number($m, '-00') , '-', $parts[2], format-number($H, 'T00'), format-number(number($parts[5]), ':00'), ':00'))" />
</xsl:function>
```

---

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qaHaQz/2

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if it might be amenable to parsing using the `parse-ietf-date()` function in XSLT 3.0

Comment: I don't think so: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qaHaQz/1